# Multiple stored procedures in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm new to using C# in Visual Studio 2010, so my knowledge is fairly limited.
I am looking to make a program that runs and exports multiple Stored Procedures in SQL Server 2008 - also with a nice interface.
The thing I am unsure about is how this is best done?

I was thinking that I want a form with maybe a treeview and a datagridview and then execute the stored procedures. This works fine with just one query - but my question is how this is done best with multiple querys? I don't want different datagridviews for each stored procedure (I have a lot). I want to be able to select a different stored procedure in my treeview and have the data in the datagridview to change without having to run the Stored Procedure every time. Some of them are pretty timeconsuming (> 1 min). So I quess what I am asking is, if I can somehow load all the data into my program at once? 
Can I get a dataset to hold more than one table - or will I somehow have to create different datasets for all my stored procedures?

Comment: It sounds like you're designing SQL Server Management Studio Express :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than load all the data into the program at once, what you want is to *cache* the results of a query the first time you run it.  This stops people having to wait for everything to load just so they can look at one data set.

Your scenario as you describe it at the moment is that when you click a particular item in the tree view, the relevant SQL is run and the collection of results is bound to your datagridview, wiping out any previous data.

The practice of caching inserts a get-if-I-don't-already-have-it layer and a method of storing.  Something like this:

```
public class MyResultClass
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}

private static readonly Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyResultClass>> 
    CachedResults = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyResultClass>>();

protected void OnTreeViewSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I'm not overly familar with the treeview off the top of my head,
    // so get selectedValue however you would normally.
    var selectedValue = ????;
    IEnumerable<MyResultClass> results;

    // Try to find the already cached results and if false, load them 
    if (!CachedResults.TryGet(selectedValue, out results))
    {
        // GetResults should use your current methodology for getting the results
        results = GetResults(selectedValue);
        CachedResults.Add(selectedValue, results);
    }

    myGridView.DataSource = results;
}
```

Note: If this is a web application rather than a winforms one, you'll need to use a ConcurrentDictionary instead of a Dictionary to make this pattern thread safe.

Comment: As the rookie I am, I cannot quite figure out what the `IEnumerable<Results>>` is. Mostly the 'Results' part.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more descriptive. Results is The Type for your data.  I've updated my post.  It's whatever the collection was when you were grabbing the information and binding it directly.  So if it wasn't an enumerable but a string, you'd cache strings.  If you were retrieving a DataTable, cache DataTable instead of IEnumerable, and so on.

Comment: Haha you put me on a test here, had to figure out a lot of stuff, but this was really helpfull. Everything works like a charm now - thanks ;-)